# MySQL SELECT multipule rows; based on variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that looks similar to this:
ID | MESSAGE  |  TO |  FROM  |  DATE

I need to query this database to check if `NameA` matches `TO` or `NameB` matches `FROM`. I also want to display these in order from newest to oldest (based on `date`).

Comment: How are you running your queries? mysql_* functions? PDO?

Comment: If you need anything more detailed than below, you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: `TO | FROM` - Be careful with that. Those are two MySQL reserved keywords. Plus, your question falls under SQL basics 101. Do Google "MySQL tutorials". We're not here to write code for you; show us what you tried.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the tip. I also want to apologize, I had forgotten about the OR statement. I was on my phone at the time witch is why i didn't add code examples.

Comment: You're welcome Wyatt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysqli_query($link, `SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE `to`='[NAMEA]' OR `from`='[NAMEB]' ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

That's the short answer. Sure, it can be improved, but this will depend on the structure of your table, the type of function you are using to access your database, etc.

**Keep in mind: Do *NOT* use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and may contain security vulnerabilities.** Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. More documentation on these functions can be found at [php.net](http://www.php.net/).